# Product Notation Conventions

Tags: notation, products, convention

If a product has the following notation, does that mean the product has zero terms? If there is an expression after this symbol, is the entire quantity, with the product symbol included, equal to zero? What is the proper notation for this, if the product must always start at g=1?
$$\prod_{g=1}^{0}$$

Comment: I'd say it equals $1$, the multiplicative identity.

Comment: Confirmed with wikipedia! Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) is $1$. Since $\prod_{a\in S}a=\frac{\prod_{c\in S\cup T}c}{\prod_{b\in T}}$ for disjoint sets $S,\,T$, the choice $S=\emptyset,\,0\not\in T$ gives $$x:=\prod_{b\in T}\ne 0\implies\prod_{a\in\emptyset}a=\frac{x}{x}=1.$$This, for example, is the logic behind $0!=1$, or the "product" $\prod_{a\in\{d\}}a=d$ of one object $d$.